# How to use Firebase for a two-sided marketplace?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a two-sided marketplace with users and merchants.

My issue is that I am currently using one Firebase project to handle both the User and Merchant authentication. This lets Users can sign into the Merchant site and Merchants sign into the User site.

Can I use DB rules to fix this or do I need to create two separate Firebase projects?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two Firebase projects. You can just assign attributes to users. For example, create a collection for each user when they sign up. Add an 'admin' key to each user object and set it to true or false depending on if they are admin or not. Render pages conditionally based on whether the user's admin flag is true or false. This takes care of the UI. As a user, you could hack your way around this if you wanted to. So make sure that you have read and write security rules set up to only let admins do admin stuff. You will still need to rely on that admin boolean I mentioned to write the rules, otherwise, you wouldn't have any way of identifying who's an admin.

Comment: This is a lovely and very correct answer but I would really like to see a very short and simple users structure (with admin key true/false) and an example rule that would  only allow admins to access a specific node. That would go a long way to help the OP and thousands of other readers. Just a thought!

Comment: There are courses for that kind of thing. I think stack is more for help when you get stuck on a specific problem rather than helping with explanations from the foundation up. Frontend Masters has an excellent [course on Firebase and React](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/firebase-react/) that covers authentication and security rules with the realtime database. I wrote a similar article on [authentication with React and the new firestore database](https://joshpitzalis.svbtle.com/auth).